# Reverse tether Nexus5x to OSX El Capitan

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, android, internet-sharing

How can I configure a Nexus5x to connect to the internet over it's USB connection while I am developing apps for it on OSX El Capitan? i'd prefer to not root the phone

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for a reverse tethering solution that would work on unrooted Android devices and OS X, but I could not find anything that really worked.

Eventually, I started to develop my own solution. The result is an app that works on devices running Android 4.0 or higher on client side, and all major desktop OSs on the host side.

The app is available on Google Play: [ReverseTethering NoRoot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.floriandraschbacher.reversetethering.free)

Comment: I played around with that a bit, but the app I was trying to connect had an issue with the VPN so It didn't work. Otherwise, it seemed nice.